# How to get list of banned IPs from Filezilla FTP Server for Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ftp

Filezilla FTP server provides with a ban of ips after a certain amount of attempts.  How I can get the IPs being banned.

Answer (score 11):

**Manually:**

To view/edit the banned IPs launch FileZilla Server.exe and click Edit > Settings

In settings you'll find the section:

-General Settings
--IP Filter

Here you can enter new bans, wildcards, even regular expressions including hostnames and it gives you some information about how to do that in the IP Filter pane.

**If you wanted to use a script to make a log or something:**

The banned list is stored in FileZilla Server.xml in your Program Files\FileZilla Server\ folder.

It's under the item:
    `<Item name="IP Filter Disallowed" type="string">1.2.3.4</Item>`

You could use any text search/parsing solution to extract the list pretty easily :)

**Autobanned IPs**

Near as I can tell after testing these are only stored in RAM.
I set off the Autoban on my server while running Process Monitor and saw only network traffic from FileZilla server.exe and nothing from FileZilla Server Interface.exe. No registry, no file access, no launching other processes...

You might try scanning RAM with a hex editor if you need to capture these values... however, you should know FileZilla recommends you do not use the Autoban feature as it can be used to cause a DoS attack and block entire VPNs/Proxies. They say in future releases this feature will be removed.

I don't anticipate a fix for this issue.

Comment: You are right sir, thanks for sharing this piece of information!

Comment: Thanks Garrett. One question: if you enable AutoBan and I attempt 30 times with the wrong password, and I get my IP banned.  Will that IP  be stored/logged under the IP Filter section?

Comment: Check out the update I posted under Autobanned IPs